# Set a prop's default value as another prop's value? (PropTypes)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a prop `driven` that takes its value from another prop `source`. `driven` can be passed a value itself, breaking that link, but by default it follows it.

Setting a default prop for `source` is straightforward, but how can I reference `source` in `driven`'s default prop.

```js
const Example = ({source = 'foo', driven = source}) => <div />

Example.defaultProps = {
  source: 'foo',
  driven: /* ? */
}
```

Comment: The use of `defaultProps` is discouraged. I would move to using TypeScript instead, or add JSDoc to your function for intellisense in your IDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mr.Polywhirl. Typescript is next on the menu for me, and I use JSDoc in tandem with Proptypes for now. Guess Typescript can't come soon enough. Unless I get a solid solution for this question, I may just leave that specific prop out of `defaultProps`

Answer (score 0):

If you need `driven` to be an alias for `source`, you can use a nullish-coalescing operation inside the component memoization:

```
/* 
 * Does something. If driven is not passed, it will be aliased to source.
 *
 * @param {string} driven
 * @param {string} [source=foo]
 */
const Example = ({ driven, source = 'foo' }) => {
  const drivenOrSource = React.useMemo(() => driven ?? source, [driven, source]);
  return <div />;
};

Example.displayName = 'Example'; // Give the anonymous function a name

// Superseded by ES5/6 prop default params
Example.defaultProps = {
  source: 'foo'
}

Example.propTypes = {
  driven: PropTypes.string,
  source: PropTypes.string
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I'm at fault for using the wrong simplified example. In my actual case, the equivalent of `driven` isnt an alias for `source` in the literal sense, it's used in a different part of the component. `source` is a transition duration, and `driven` is a timeout that acts as a failsafe. By default, the failsafe takes the duration prop, be it default or passed, unless the parent overrides the failsafe to another value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the function for default prop value of `driven`. I am the fan of typescript so just change your code in typescript.

```js
interface ExampleProps {
    source: string;
    driven: (props: ExampleProps) => string;
  }
  
  const Example: React.FC<ExampleProps> = ({source = 'foo', driven = source}) => (
    <div>{source} - {driven}</div>
  );
  
  Example.defaultProps = {
    source: 'foo',
    driven: function(props: ExampleProps) {
      return props.source;
    },
  };
  export default Example
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I certainly plan to move to Typescript in my next project. I'm hoping for a pure JS solution for now, if that's even possible, but still thanks!